# Wrap MySQL Column Name

Tags: mysql

Surely this has been asked before, but my searches haven't turned up a solution.

Is there a way in MySQL to wrap the column names? I know I can alias them as shorter names, but they're already as short as they can be while still being descriptive.

I want something like:

```
SELECT u.longcolumnname AS 'Long <br/> Column <br/> Name'
```

to return:

```
Long
Column
Name
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: that's not SQL's job. If you want pretty column names, then you either use `AS whatever` aliases in your queries as needed, or you do the "ugly"->"readable but way too long" translations in your client app.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to really nerd it up, check out the BNF definition for SQL such as 
http://savage.net.au/SQL/sql-2003-2.bnf

what a select list is:

```
<select list> ::= <asterisk> | <select sublist> [ { <comma> <select sublist> }... ]
<select sublist> ::= <derived column> | <qualified asterisk>
<derived column list> ::= <column name list>
<column name list> ::= <column name> [ { <comma> <column name> }... ]
<column name> ::= <identifier>
<identifier> ::= <actual identifier>
<actual identifier> ::= <regular identifier> | <delimited identifier>
<regular identifier> ::= <identifier body>
<delimited identifier> ::= <double quote> <delimited identifier body> <double quote>
<delimited identifier body> ::= <delimited identifier part>... 
<delimited identifier part> ::= <nondoublequote character> | <doublequote symbol>
<nondoublequote character> ::= !! See the Syntax Rules.

Syntax rule 6: A <nondoublequote character> is any character of
the source language character set other than a <double quote>.
```

By the way you can include newlines / carriage returns in the select and it works.

From my DB

```
select startTime as "Start
Time"
 from queries;
```

When I copy the value out of MySQL client (right click copy row with names), I get

```
# start
Time
'1392061991'
```

So MySQL did include the carriage return.  However the column name shown in MySQL client is only one line and it only shows "start" because the rest is below it.

Comment: Putting a carriage return in the column alias generates an error in my client app (Moodle). But thanks for the suggestion!